# Is it safe to exercise while in the shower?

Tags: safety

I've had the idea of doing squats while I was in the shower to be able to do exercises simultaneously with another task. Given the size of my current shower room, I won't be able to do other exercises such as pushups, lunges, etc.

Is there any risk for my body to do exercises while taking a shower?

Comment: Why exactly did I get downvotes?

Comment: Because it's dangerous, applies to very few other individuals, and of no real practical use. No healthy person with good muscle strength is attributing it to squats while showering, bench pressing while shaving, or whatever other silliness. Prioritize your fitness, or you'll prioritize illness and injury: there's no third option.

Comment: I personally do 3 or 4 in the morning while waiting for the water to warm up, but it's before I get in the water. I don't figure that it's going to make a huge difference in my fitness, but it's a good way to get my body in the habit of being up and moving in the morning.

Comment: @EricKaufman - Then what it needs is a good answer, rather than downvotes where it would be put in the depths of SO, where people wouldn't be informed that it actually is dangerous.

Comment: Doing 3 or 4 bodyweight squats while waiting for hot water doesn't do anything for you, unless you're very obese. If you're doing it to "wake up", how about just stepping into the cold shower? And also, I think you're extremely aware of the risk factors related to physical exercise on a hard, wet, slippery surface. This is likely the reason for the downvote.

Comment: @MarkGabriel - No, that isn't what it needs. And unless you have high rep, highly downvoted questions are not visible. It needs to be downvoted and closed. A bad question is a bad question, and a good answer "For the benefit of others" is not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not safe to exercise while in the shower. More importantly, ***the cost-benefit ratio is too high*** for this to be effective.

Let's consider the ***"supposed"*** benefits:

**1. Burning calories:** How much calories can you realistically burn? Your calorie burn is determined by your **intensity** and the **duration**. Your intensity will be low because you're careful not to hurt yourself. The duration will be low too because it's quite unlikely for you to spend more than 10 minutes squatting in the shower.

As a result, the actual calories burned will be low.

**2. Multi-tasking *( in order to burn calories while performing other tasks):*** Multi-tasking is awesome in the right environment and context. Squatting while showering isn't a good combination for multi-tasking since both actions require some form of concentration to function properly; otherwise, there'll be no benefit for either action *(you won't be effectively clean and your exercise form will suffer)*. You're better off performing your exercises and then showering.

And now for the costs:

**1. You can *(and very likely)* will hurt yourself. Jumping or squatting on a slippery ground is a bad idea.** Not only can you slip, but the motion can cause temporary disorientation that'll result in you falling. Hitting your head or vital parts of your body against the bathroom's hard surfaces is much more likely to occur.

**2. A lot of bath areas are too small to accommodate effective exercises**. Exercises that really burn calories *(running, plyometrics)* just can't be performed in small, contained location.

**3. Some exercises just aren't feasible in the shower.** Performing push ups in the shower *(in pools of water)* is both disgusting and unhealthy.

**4. Sweating while showering makes little sense**. If your goal of showering is to clean yourself, but you manage to generate enough intensity to create a sweat, what's the purpose of the shower?

**5. You can injure yourself.** This is worth repeating. **If you exercise in the shower, you'll hurt yourself sooner or later** *(it's not a matter of "if", it's a matter of "when")*.

The benefit you'll gain is minute, compared to the potential cost. You're better off exercising **before** showering.

Optimal solution is this: ***create dedicated periods to exercise, eat right, have quality sleep, and incorporate exercising/movements in your daily life*** and you'll have no need for injury-prone disasters such as exercising while showering.

Comment: Nice, but why do you people always forget about the crucial SLEEP QUALITY? Exercise, yes. Eat right, yes. Sleep is missing from the list but it is as important as the others!

Comment: @Mephisto Lol....I always forget about quality sleep; I've added quality sleep to my answer :).

Answer (score 0):

There's an increased slip risk, which combines with the possibility of falling face-first into standing water (from a clogged drain or one temporarily clogged by your fallen body). [Drowning in an inch of water](http://www.realhomesafety.com/drowning.htm) happens. Given you're going to take longer to shower most likely anyhow due to going in and out of the water stream, I'd advise against this. Instead, use your toothcare time to do the same thing. It's safe to do squats while brushing your teeth and using mouthwash.

Comment: It's safe to do squats while brushing your teeth *unless you faceplant and jam the brush down your throat*.

Comment: :) Yeah, but I figure the odds of that are really no worse than tripping while standing and doing the same.